# x64: Why does this piece of code give me "Address boundary error"

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, x86-64, att

Why does the following x64 assembly give me "Address boundary error"? It only happens when I add code after `call _print_string`. I assume that some of the register have been modified but aren't they supposed to be reverted once the `_print_string` function returns?

**I am using Mac OS X**

```
obj_size = 8

.data
    hello_world: .asciz "hello world!"

.text
    .globl _main


_main:

    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    leaq hello_world(%rip), %rdi
    callq _print_string

    subq obj_size, %rsp
    movq 1, %rax
    movq %rax, obj_size(%rsp)

    addq obj_size, %rsp


    leave
    ret
```

And the C program is:

```
void
print_string(char *str) 
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: Which OS? Some registers are NOT preserved, and which ones are preserved differs from OS to OS.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I am using Mac OS X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with this code is pretty simple. In GNU Assembler using AT&T syntax -
 literal constants that are used as an immediate operand need to be prefixed with a `$` (dollar sign) otherwise the constant is treated as a memory operand.

These lines all have this issue:

```
subq obj_size, %rsp
movq 1, %rax
[snip]
addq obj_size, %rsp
```

In these cases since you want to use the constants `obj_size` and `1` as a value (immediate operand) and not a memory reference. The instructions above should have been:

```
subq $obj_size, %rsp
movq $1, %rax
[snip]
addq $obj_size, %rsp
```

`subq obj_size, %rsp` attempted to subtract the 64-bit value at memory address 0x8 from the value in *RSP*. `movq 1, %rax` attempted to move the 64-bit value at memory address 0x1 into *RAX*. Your program faulted since those memory locations on OS/X can't be read from.

A good article on the difference between AT&T syntax and Intel syntax can be found on [IBM's website](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gas-nasm/). In particular they have this difference listed:

> In AT&T syntax, immediate operands are preceded by $; in Intel syntax, immediate operands are not. For example: Intel: `push 4`, AT&T: `pushl $4`

---

To narrow down problems like these it is often beneficial to use a debugger. On OS/X if you are not using Xcode you can use the debugger *LLDB* from the command line. A [tutorial on using *LLDB*](https://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html) may be useful. In this case you could have run *LLDB* as `lldb ./nameofprogram` and then used the `run` command to allow it to continue until it failed. The debugger would have then shown you what assembly instruction the crash occurred at.

---

If you want to know the calling convention used by 64-bit OS/X code [Apple defines it this way](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/140-x86-64_Function_Calling_Conventions/x86_64.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005035-SW1):

> The OS X x86-64 function calling conventions are the same as the function calling conventions described in System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement.

You can find the System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf). The list of caller and callee saved registers can be found in *Figure 3.4: Register Usage*